# Confused with the Websphere coredump file in Linux

Tags: linux, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1

sometimes i can see core dump file of Websphere process generated in my Linux system. I think it as full core file. However, when i check with `ulimit -a`, that would return with `core file size 0` as one of them.
   From my understanding, that `core file size 0` means no core dump file would be produced in that environment. But if so, why that Websphere Application Server process can it happen at that moment?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the process environment of the actual running JVM?  Are you sure they're native corefiles and not javacores only?

Comment: ...or IBM Java system core files (core.yyyyddmm.hhMMdd.pid.seq.dmp)? What is the filename you're concerned with?

Comment: @bkail it's core.yyyyddmm.hhMMdd.pid.seq.dmp file that i'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

By default, IBM Java will create a system dump in some situations as explained in the [System dump defaults](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.60/diag/tools/coredump_defaults.html) article of the IBM Java 6 InfoCenter.  You can see those situations with the following command:

```
/path/to/WebSphere/ApplicationServer/java/bin/java -Xdump:what
```

System dumps are useful for IBM service to determine what has gone wrong with your JVM, so depending on the circumstance, you might want to open PMR.

If you really want to disable these dumps, then add `-Xdump:system:none` to the "Generic JVM Arguments" of your server as explained in the [Configuring the JVM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/trun_jvm.html) article of the WebSphere Application Server InfoCenter.